What is the process of upgrading druid cluster from 0.17 to a 0.22.1
I have a Druid cluster running version 0.17 and I'm planning to upgrade it to version 0.22.1. I am looking for guidance on the best practices and steps to follow for this upgrade.

What are the key steps involved in upgrading a Druid cluster from 0.17 to 0.22.1?
Are there any critical configuration changes or migrations that I need to be aware of?
Should I consider upgrading Kafka or any other dependencies as part of this process? If so, what versions are recommended?
How can I ensure a smooth and minimally disruptive upgrade process for my production environment?
Are there any known issues or pitfalls with this upgrade that I should watch out for?

I've already set up two versions of the Druid cluster, but I'm unsure about the next steps.

All release notes for Druid versions are published online, and include an "upgrading to" section.

18
19
20
21
22

It is important, as with any upgrade across versions that span the time period of releases that you are covering, to read these carefully. These will give you answers on what changes are being made.
These also include notes on changes to compatible versions of dependencies, such as Zookeeper.
At time of writing, Druid 30 is the current version. This version includes the "multi-stage query engine" which provides (amongst other things) SQL-based batch ingestion and query direct from deep storage, and the "start-druid" script (which I find very useful myself). Therefore if you are going to the effort of upgrading, consider whether a version beyond (at least) 26 would be to your advantage.
More release notes can be found on the official site. Look for any tag that has a "Notes" icon.

https://github.com/apache/druid/tags

As regards the process, see the documentation on rolling upgrades:

Rolling upgrades

